# Data modified show old value when called after update

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my app I have a method that updates the values of an item like this:

```
foreach (var orderDetailInfo in _order.mListOrderDetail)
{
    OrderDetailInfo info = orderDetailInfo;

    var inventoryQry = from i in db.INVENTORY
                       where i.INVENT_IDE == info.mInventoryID
                       select i;

    INVENTORY originalItem = inventoryQry.Single();

    INVENTORY itemToModify = originalItem;

    itemToModify.INVENT_NB_IN_STOCK = (orderDetailInfo.mOrderDetailQuantity +
                                       originalItem.INVENT_NB_IN_STOCK);

    db.Entry(originalItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(itemToModify);

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now if I look in the table at the `originalItem`, is value is updated. Say that before being updated, its value was 4, and the `order` updated the quantity to 5.

My problem is that when I load the data like this after the upper code has run (so, after I update the `INVENT_NB_IN_STOCK` column):

```
var inventoryQry = from inv in db.INVENTORY
                   where inv.INVENT_IDE == inventIDE
                   select inv;

return inventoryQry.Single();
```

The item shows **the last value it holded before building**, and not the current value. In this case, the value would be 4, not 5. Why? Can anyone help me figure out my problem?

Since it might be because of a huge method I make, I am posting here the entire method which contains the chunk of code displayed up here:

```
internal void ValidateSupplierOrder(OrderInfo _order, List<OrderDetailInfo> _listOldOrderDetails)
{
    using (BlueBerry_MTGEntities db = new BlueBerry_MTGEntities())
    {
        using (TransactionScope scope = TransactionUtils.CreateTransactionScope())
        {
            try
            {
                ORDERS orderToModify = DataConverter.OrderInfoToOrderDATA(_order);

                var orderQry = from o in db.ORDERS
                               where o.ORDER_IDE == _order.mOrderID
                               select o;

                ORDERS originalOrder = orderQry.Single();

                // First step: we need to remove the old order details as they are no more related
                // To the order we are currently adding.
                foreach (var orderDetail in _listOldOrderDetails)
                {
                    OrderDetailInfo detail = orderDetail;

                    var orderDetailQry = from od in db.ORDER_DETAIL
                                         where od.ORDER_DETAIL_IDE == detail.mOrderDetailID
                                         select od;

                    ORDER_DETAIL itemToRemove = orderDetailQry.SingleOrDefault();

                    db.ORDER_DETAIL.Remove(itemToRemove);

                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                foreach (ORDER_DETAIL orderDetailToCreate in _order.mListOrderDetail.Select(DataConverter.OrderDetailInfoToOrderDetailDATA))
                {
                    db.ORDER_DETAIL.Add(orderDetailToCreate);

                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                foreach (var orderDetailInfo in _order.mListOrderDetail)
                {
                    OrderDetailInfo info = orderDetailInfo;

                    var inventoryQry = from i in db.INVENTORY
                                       where i.INVENT_IDE == info.mInventoryID
                                       select i;

                    INVENTORY originalItem = inventoryQry.Single();

                    INVENTORY itemToModify = originalItem;

                    itemToModify.INVENT_NB_IN_STOCK = (orderDetailInfo.mOrderDetailQuantity +
                                                       originalItem.INVENT_NB_IN_STOCK);

                    db.Entry(originalItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(itemToModify);

                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                db.Entry(originalOrder).CurrentValues.SetValues(orderToModify);

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }

            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that you originally had this tagged as `asp.net-mvc`.  If you are just doing a post and returning the view, the values might be cached in your `ModelState`.  You can try clearing that, or use the Post/Redirect/Get pattern.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get.

Comment: I've tried to clear the modelstate as you suggest, then I checked and our application is mostly built on the Post/Redirect/Get pattern (mostly). Still, the GOOD value is shown only when the project is rebuilt, that's why it puzzles me.

Comment: Maybe it is because I actually try to modify only a field of the object, but create an object based on the `originalItem`?

Comment: Seems like that was it. I need to test further to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out the issue, which was due to... my own missing knowledge!

Let's take these lines of codes:

```
foreach (var orderDetailInfo in _order.mListOrderDetail)
{
    OrderDetailInfo info = orderDetailInfo;

    var inventoryQry = from i in db.INVENTORY
                       where i.INVENT_IDE == info.mInventoryID
                       select i;

    INVENTORY originalItem = inventoryQry.Single();

    INVENTORY itemToModify = originalItem;

    itemToModify.INVENT_NB_IN_STOCK = (orderDetailInfo.mOrderDetailQuantity +
                                       originalItem.INVENT_NB_IN_STOCK);

    db.Entry(originalItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(itemToModify);

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

My guess was (and is) that somehow the pattern I use to modify the value was not the good one. Maybe it was because I was copying an object instead of creating a new one and setting the actual values to what I needed.

So I did this:

```
foreach (var orderDetailInfo in _order.mListOrderDetail)
{
    OrderDetailInfo info = orderDetailInfo;

    var inventoryQry = from i in db.INVENTORY
                       where i.INVENT_IDE == info.mInventoryID
                       select i;

    INVENTORY originalItem = inventoryQry.Single();

    int newStock = (int)(info.mOrderDetailQuantity + originalItem.INVENT_NB_IN_STOCK);

    INVENTORY itemToModify = new INVENTORY
        {
            CARD_IDE = originalItem.CARD_IDE,
            INVENT_IDE = originalItem.INVENT_IDE,
            INVENT_ITEM_STATE = originalItem.INVENT_ITEM_STATE,
            INVENT_NB_IN_STOCK = newStock,
            INVENT_NB_QT_ADJUST = 0,
            INVENT_NB_QT_EBAY_AUCTION = originalItem.INVENT_NB_QT_EBAY_AUCTION,
            INVENT_NB_QT_EBAY_STORE = originalItem.INVENT_NB_QT_EBAY_STORE,
            INVENT_NB_QT_FINEP = originalItem.INVENT_NB_QT_FINEP,
            INVENT_NB_QT_SEND = 0,
            INVENT_NB_QT_SOLD = originalItem.INVENT_NB_QT_SOLD
        };

    db.Entry(originalItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(itemToModify);

    db.Entry(originalItem).State = EntityState.Modified;

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

And although it does not seems elegant, it works!